# Why does parallel processing not speed this up more?

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing

I am trying to figure out how to use parallel processing. For this purpose I've made a function to test speeds. However, I am only getting double speeds when using 4 cores instead of 1, why is this?

Example code:

```
as <- runif(30)  # limit for 
bs <- runif(30)
cs <- runif(30)  # distribution of food sources ('random'/'clustered')

p_space <- list ()
for (a in as){
  for (b in bs){
    for (c in cs){
      p_space[[length(p_space)+1]] <- c(a,b,c)
    }
  }
}
made_up <- function(pvec){
  a <- pvec[1]
  b <- pvec[2]
  c <- pvec[3]
  for(i in 1:10000){
    d <- a*b*c
  }
  return(list(a,b,c,d))
}
system.time({
  z <- lapply(p_space,made_up)
  results1 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(z),ncol = 4, byrow = T))
  colnames(results1) <- c('a','b','c','product')

})

 user  system elapsed 
  21.23    0.01   21.26

library(parallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() 
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl, c("p_space"))
# clusterEvalQ() #for libraries on all nodes
system.time ({
  z <- parLapply(cl, p_space, made_up)
  results <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(z),ncol = 4, byrow = T))
  colnames(results) <- c('a','b','c','product')
})

user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.02   10.86
```

N.B I checked and there are 4 cores in the cluster it makes and they are all running (cpu performance = 100% for parallel, vs 25% when not)

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why you think you should get more than a doubling of speed with double the number of cores.

Comment: there are 4x the number of cores (I just saw my typo in question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your system has two *physical* cores that support hyperthreading to appear like four cores. You can test this by comparing the output of these commands:

```
detectCores(logical = FALSE) 
#> 2    
detectCores() 
#> 4
```

The above values are from my system which gives similar performance results to yours. But using only the two physical cores gives the same performance as using the four logical ones. Analogy: You have two counters where people can be served, each of them with two possible queues. If all people are sent to one queue, it looks like only 25% of the capacity is used. If they are sent to all four queues, it looks like 100% is used. However, there are only two counters open, so there is (almost) no gain from going from two queues to four queues.

Comment: Ah I see! I had no idea. So why does the CPU increase in use from 25% to 100%?

Comment: @DomBurns Your OS is only looking from the outside, i.e. "how many queues are filled" in the analogy I added above.